Is it appropriate to use KL Divergence as a loss function for a 1x3 regression model?
I have a regression model with a 1x3 output, which means it predicts three continuous values. I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to use the Kullback-Leibler (KL) Divergence as the loss function for this model.
I understand that KL Divergence is a measure of the difference between two probability distributions. However, in my case, the model is not predicting probability distributions but rather three continuous values.
Could someone please explain why KL Divergence would not be a suitable loss function for this regression problem? And what would be a more appropriate loss function to use instead?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

KL divergence is defined as the number of bits required to convert one distribution into another. The lower bound value is zero and is achieved when the distributions under observation are identical.
It measures the difference between two probability distributions. It is typically used in settings where the model outputs a probability distribution, such as in variational autoencoders (VAEs) or other probabilistic models.
In the context of regression, it would be needed that your model needs to output a distribution over possible outcomes rather than a single point estimate. As such you'd require your target y_true to be a distribution as well.
It'd be easier to use a different model with this loss if you were trying to predict something like that.
